# Getting count of rows that have values within a value range MySQL

Tags: mysql

Supposed I have this table

```
id |  value
----------
1  |  1
2  |  1
3  |  2
4  |  4
5  |  7
6  |  10
7  |  12
8  |  13
```

I want to know how can I get a result such that each row will have an additional value that is the count of rows that have value within 1 unit of that row value.
With that said, the answer should look something like this

```
id |  value | count
--------------
1  |  1     |  3
2  |  1     |  3
3  |  2     |  3
4  |  4     |  1
5  |  7     |  1
6  |  10    |  1
7  |  12    |  2
8  |  13    |  2
```

My description is probaly confusing but this is the best explanation I could come up with. I have tried hours to find a method for this kind of merging but I am still stuck.

I hope someone can tell me what can I do to make this happen in MySQL (this problem is transformation of a simple programming array problem, but I was unable to do it in MySQL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option uses a join followed by an aggregation:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.value,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON ABS(t1.value - t2.value) <= 1
GROUP BY
    t1.value, t1.id;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that we need to `GROUP BY` both the `id` and `value`.  The reason for this is that we want to logically aggregate by each *record* in the original table, which is denoted by the combination of the `id` and `value` columns.  If we were to group by only the `value`, then we would get incorrect counts, because, e.g., the value `1` would match to multiple other records in the self join.

Comment: Thank you so much! By the way, at first I tried the GROUP BY with just t1.value only, but it gives me a weird result that I have no idea where do they come from. But after I added t1.id in GROUP BY then it works properly. Can you explain that part too?

Comment: @NamNguyễn In fact I also made this mistake initially, until I tested my code.  We need to `GROUP BY` both the `id` and `value`, to address each unique record in your table.